# Ap calculus: critical number of $F(x)=x^2-3x-\frac{4}{x}-2$

Tags: calculus

(A) find the critical numbers of f if any(B) find the open interval(s) on which the function is increasing or decreasing (C) apply the First Derivative Test to identifying all relative extrema (D) use a graphing utility to confirm your results
$F(x)=x^2-3x-\frac{4}{x}-2$
**My Attempt**
I have started by finding the derivative which is $x^2-4x+\frac{10}{(x-2)^2} $then equaled it to 0. After that, I'm not too sure what to do.

Comment: Hi, can you show us if you have tried anything to solve this question of yours?

Comment: Yes i have found the derivative

Comment: People here would be more willing to give you hints or a partial solution if you included the stuff you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly:

$a.)$ Given a function $f(x)$, we calculate the derivative of this function and set it equal to $0$: $f'(x)=0$

We then solve for $x$ using the resulting equation. We set the zeroes of $f'(x)$ as $c$ for easier notation.

$b.)$ Using the values of $c$ that we obtained earlier, note that:

$$\text{if } f(x) \le f(c), f(x) \, \text{has a maximum at $x=c$}$$
$$\text{if } f(x) \ge f(c), f(x) \, \text{has a minimum at $x=c$}$$

$c.)$ Using the values of $c$ obtained, you show that for values of $x$ not equal to $c$, you will get this:

$$\text{if } f'(x) \lt 0, f(x) \, \text{is increasing}$$
$$\text{if } f'(x) \gt 0, f(x) \, \text{is decreasing}$$
$$\text{if } f'(x) = 0, f(x) \, \text{is constant}$$

Comment: Thank youu, but how do i solve for x with this type of equation x^2-4x+10/(x-2)^2=0

Comment: Derivate wrt x and then equaye it to be 0 then the value of x which ulis less than 0 is incresing slope while answer having x greater than 0 is decreasing back substitute and you get maxima and minima of the function.